# ActiveRecord includes query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, spree

Products has Variants. 
I'm trying to fetch Variants that has cost_currency: "USD"
A Variant may look like this:
`Spree::Variant id: 22, cost_currency: "USD">`

`Spree::Product.includes('variants')` returns a lot of Variants, but if I try to filter only the ones that has `cost_currency = true` it fails.

This is what I did:

```
2.2.3 :077 > Spree::Product.includes('variants')
                 .where( variants: { cost_currency: "USD" })
```

But that throws an **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: variants.cost_currency** error, which I don't understand why.

**Full stack trace:**

```
  SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT "spree_products"."id" AS t0_r0, "spree_products"."name" AS t0_r1, "spree_products"."description" 
  AS t0_r2, "spree_products"."available_on" AS t0_r3, "spree_pro
ducts"."deleted_at" AS t0_r4, "spree_products"."slug" AS t0_r5, "spree_products"."meta_description" AS t0_r6, "spree_products"."meta_keywords" AS t0_r7, "spree_products"."tax_catego
ry_id" AS t0_r8, "spree_products"."shipping_category_id" AS t0_r9, "spree_products"."created_at" AS t0_r10, "spree_products"."updated_at" AS t0_r11, "spree_products"."promotionable"
 AS t0_r12, "spree_products"."meta_title" AS t0_r13, "spree_variants"."id" AS t1_r0, "spree_variants"."sku" AS t1_r1, "spree_variants"."weight" AS t1_r2, "spree_variants"."height" A
S t1_r3, "spree_variants"."width" AS t1_r4, "spree_variants"."depth" AS t1_r5, "spree_variants"."deleted_at" AS t1_r6, "spree_variants"."is_master" AS t1_r7, "spree_variants"."produ
ct_id" AS t1_r8, "spree_variants"."cost_price" AS t1_r9, "spree_variants"."position" AS t1_r10, "spree_variants"."cost_currency" AS t1_r11, "spree_variants"."track_inventory" AS t1_
r12, "spree_variants"."tax_category_id" AS t1_r13, "spree_variants"."updated_at" AS t1_r14 FROM "spree_products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_variants" ON "spree_variants"."product_id" =
"spree_products"."id" AND "spree_variants"."is_master" = ? AND "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "variants"."cost_currency" = ?
[["is_master", "f"], ["cost_currency", "USD"]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: variants.cost_currency: SELECT "spree_products"."id" AS t0_r0, "spree_products"."name" AS t0_r1, "spree_produc
ts"."description" AS t0_r2, "spree_products"."available_on" AS t0_r3, "spree_products"."deleted_at" AS t0_r4, "spree_products"."slug" AS t0_r5, "spree_products"."meta_description" A
S t0_r6, "spree_products"."meta_keywords" AS t0_r7, "spree_products"."tax_category_id" AS t0_r8, "spree_products"."shipping_category_id" AS t0_r9, "spree_products"."created_at" AS t
0_r10, "spree_products"."updated_at" AS t0_r11, "spree_products"."promotionable" AS t0_r12, "spree_products"."meta_title" AS t0_r13, "spree_variants"."id" AS t1_r0, "spree_variants"
."sku" AS t1_r1, "spree_variants"."weight" AS t1_r2, "spree_variants"."height" AS t1_r3, "spree_variants"."width" AS t1_r4, "spree_variants"."depth" AS t1_r5, "spree_variants"."dele
ted_at" AS t1_r6, "spree_variants"."is_master" AS t1_r7, "spree_variants"."product_id" AS t1_r8, "spree_variants"."cost_price" AS t1_r9, "spree_variants"."position" AS t1_r10, "spre
e_variants"."cost_currency" AS t1_r11, "spree_variants"."track_inventory" AS t1_r12, "spree_variants"."tax_category_id" AS t1_r13, "spree_variants"."updated_at" AS t1_r14 FROM "spre
e_products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_variants" ON "spree_variants"."product_id" = "spree_products"."id" AND "spree_variants"."is_master" = ? AND "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL
WHERE "spree_products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "variants"."cost_currency" = ?
```

Comment: try `where("spree_variants.cost_currency = 'USD'")` or `where( spree_variants: {cost_currency:  'USD' } )`

Comment: you can check what is the name of the table in the database.. using `ModelsName.table_name` and then reference our columns accordingly. like `where("#{Spree::Variant.table_name}.cost_currency = 'USD'")`

Comment: do it like `Spree::Product.includes(:variants).where('spree_variants.cost_currency = "USD" ' )` or `Spree::Product.includes('variants').where('spree_variants.cost_currency = "USD" ' )`. includes should not contain **table name** but the **relation name** in your `ActiveRecord`. and for **conditions i.e. `where`** you should use **table name** and **column name**

Comment: Didn't know about `.table_name`. Thanks! :-)  This worked: `Spree::Product.includes('variants').where( spree_variants: {cost_currency: 'USD' } )` Post it as an answer. :-)

Comment: No problem dude.. :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try doing

```
Spree::Product.includes(:variants).where('spree_variants.cost_currency = "USD"')
```

or

```
Spree::Product.includes('variants').where('spree_variants.cost_currency = "USD" ' )
```

or

```
Spree::Product.includes('variants').where(spree_variants: { cost_currency: 'USD' })
```

Comment: you posted the wrong answer. This is the one that works: `Spree::Product.includes('variants').where( spree_variants: {cost_currency: 'USD' } )`  ;-P

Comment: @martins Thanks.. But the above given answer should work too

Comment: @martins I added that as well